# How to set 2 domains on 1 website?

Tags: dns

How to set multilanguage website to have few domains: www.zzz.com/content and www.zzz.eu/content?
I tried MultiDomain and domain mirror plugins but nothing works (the second domain was forwarded). Then tried to set the same DNS for both domains, still no result..

Comment: This is not really a WordPress question. You're trying to route domains and configure the server. Migrating to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for DNS changes to propagate. This is based on the TTL value, but if your DNS provider complies with the RFC recommendations will be no shorter than twelve hours.

Setting two domains to point to the same IP address will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some kind of domain name forward for you urls with your DNS so you have a configuration like:

```
www.zzz.com -> your.site.com
www.zzz.eu  -> your.site.com
```

This is something that has to be done with the DNS, not on your website.